# Citation for essay in Analog about speed of travel

Tags: story-identification, technology, space-exploration

I recall, as a child in the 1970's, reading an essay that I think was in *Analog* about the speed of technological progress and, in particular, the fastest modes of travel. There was a plot of fastest modes of travel over time (I think it was one that has more recently been featured in the book *What Technology Wants*), and the author was arguing that we should take seriously the prediction implied by the plot that interstellar travel would be possible by 2010 or so.

I realize the article I'm looking for isn't itself science fiction, but it's in a science fiction publication, and so I think this community would be better suited to answer it than anybody, and (I hope) interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems like an article by G. Harry Stine (Lee Correy) from about 1960 or so.

"Science Fiction is Too Conservative"  *Analog* 1961.

[enter link description here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?G._Harry_Stine)https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?G._Harry_Stine

Back in the 1960s I read it in a science fiction anthology which is NOT in the following list:

[enter link description here](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?117600)https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?117600

Comment: Thanks! I'm almost sure that's it. I was already able to track down a graph that I think he modified for his essay, by a guy named D. G. Samaras. IIRC it was part of an Air Force study. The reason I was looking for this is that I want to make the point that science fiction is not, in fact, too conservative. Or at least it was not then. Now I just need to dig up a copy of the anthology.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like one of the articles in Arthur C. Clarke's *"Profiles of the Future"* (referred to [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke#Futurism)).

You can [Look Inside on Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Profiles-Of-The-Future-Possible/dp/0575402776).